# Uncaught TypeError: button.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning js on my own and I am new in programming. I am stuck on the below code and any help will be much appreciated:

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-Do list</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span> one</li>
    <li><span>X</span> two</li>
    <li><span>X</span> three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
let li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

let button = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
})
```

This throwing an error saying that it is not a function. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a **HTML Collection**, not a **single** node - so, you'll need to *iterate* through the collection (a for loop for example), adding a listener to each node in the collection

Answer (score 0):

The function [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a HTMLCollection of elements, you need to loop over it to bind the events.

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

Array.from(buttons).forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-Do list</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span> one</li>
    <li><span>X</span> two</li>
    <li><span>X</span> three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements

we can addEventListener on every element

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

let button = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

console.log(button); // list of elements

// and we have to addEventListener on every element
Array.prototype.map.call(button, (b) => {
  b.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-Do list</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span> one</li>
    <li><span>X</span> two</li>
    <li><span>X</span> three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or we can `addEventListener` on parent element (`ul` for example):

```
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target); // this will helps us to figure out on what exact element a click was made
  console.log("clicked");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the buttons like so:

```
let li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("You clicked!");
    });
});
```